# Pinned Taskbar Icons are there, but not showing

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, troubleshooting

As you can see in the screengrab, my icon for Word is not present, although the link still works. I've tried a couple of suggestions from 'the internet' but none work. For example, I've deleted the icon cache, and rebuilt it.

[image]

Any ideas on how to get it back?

Sometimes it's more than just this one icon. Also, pinned apps randomly unpin themselves. Maybe a linked problem, or may be a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

I happen with almost everyone and happened with me too, You just log off or restart your PC and you will get your icon back and if you don't want that so just unpin that icon from there and pin again any icon you want there.

Comment: Nah, they dont come back after a restart.....